# +5 to 0v square wave from a 12vdc supply

Tags: wave, 5v, square

I need to build a simple 0 to +5v square wave from a 13vdc (automobile) supply. The frequency of the output needs to be based on a 1vac input signal. I believe it can be done with a handful of resistors, diodes and transistors but I've not done electronics for over 35 years now. Can someone suggest a design please.
Thank you in advance.
Paul.

Comment: Is the duty cycle of the input the same as the output? That is, do you simply want to produce a squared-up 5v version of the input signal?

Comment: What is the input signal?  Is it a digital signal of the same shape as the desired output?  What is the amplitude of the input signal?  How much current can it supply?

Comment: Assuming that 1VAC is a sinusoid, you could use an OpAmp as a comparator. This way, the sinusoid would be converted either to saturated voltage, or zero, based on your threshold voltage  setting. Use a voltage regulator to drop the voltage from 12V to 5V for powering the opAmp.

Comment: Is this 1VAC signal fairly constant amplitude or is it something horrible like a variable reluctance sensor that is extremely variable? And what frequency is it?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. The signal I am trying to boost is the vehicle speed signal into the ECU. I have replaced a modern engine and ECU into an older car. The new ECU requires 5v the car produces 1v. I have not measured the 1v signal yet but I believe the amplitude is fairly constant 0 - 1v+ , the frequency varies with vehicle speed. I believe the newer ECU is looking for 0 - 5v+. I don't think the shape or duty cycle is important, just the frequency and amplitude.
Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 5v regulator to produce 5v from  13v. Next use a comparator such as a MAX999 and feed your a/c signal to it. That comparator will produce a sq wave with input signals at or about 0v.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going into a microcontroller, many of them have built-in comparators and all you have to do is to bias and AC-couple the input signal (maybe 2 or 3 resistors and a capacitor) so that the comparator can trigger off it. Otherwise you can use any number of comparators on the market ([LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393.pdf) is a common one that costs only pennies).

There are some details to do with the automotive environment that are not pleasant though, and without more information it is difficult to advice. All your inputs and outputs (and the power supply) should be able to withstand spikes of +/-50V or +/-100V without dying.